# Random generate characters excluding

Tags: javascript

If I have the code below to generate random characters,  how can I code it to generate those same characters excluding some values? I.e. corresponding to var charactExclude.

Ex:

```js
function makeid(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  var charactExclude = document.getelementbyID(character).content.text

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result
}

console.log(makeid(10))
```

Comment: Easiest option: Make another var with the excluded characters removed (using something like `replace()`) and use that in your selection.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives errors - please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: Also typos in `document.getelementbyID(character)` and there is no `character`

Comment: Just a side note: have you put in place some check in order to to grant that the randomly generated ID does not already exist? Otherwise you might have some unpleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about this:

- First select your element containing the excluded characters (You have some errors in your JS) You can split this into an array using `.split('')` and use the `[...new Set(Your array here)]` pattern to remove duplicates at this point.
- Then create a new variable for the filtered string, and loop through replacing the characters you do not want to include.
- Finally, use this new variable in the creation of your string.

```js
function makeid(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactExclude = [
    // Using a Set efficiently removes duplicates, and will speed up the loop below, and the ... expands them back into an array
    ...new Set(
      // Using split('') will turn the string into an array of characters
      document.getElementById("character").innerText.split('')
    )
  ];

  // Create a new variable, and then loop through the charactExclude array, removing undesired chars
  var charactersFiltered = characters
  for (var i = 0; i < charactExclude.length; i++) {
    charactersFiltered = charactersFiltered.replace(charactExclude[i], '')
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += charactersFiltered.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersFiltered.length));
  }
  return result
}

console.log(makeid(100))
```

```html
<div id="character">ABCDEFG</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that

```js
const alphabetAndNumbers = () => [...Array(26)]
      .map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 65))
      .concat([...Array(26)].map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)))
      .concat([...Array(10)].map((x, i) => `${i}`));

console.log(`Your id: ${createRandomId(10)}`);

function createRandomId(len) {
  let characters = alphabetAndNumbers();
  console.log(`[characters] initial ${characters.join("")}`);
  
  //retrieve characters to exclude from the template element and split it to an array
  const excludes = document.querySelector("#excludes").content.textContent.split("");
  
  // filter initial characters array to exclude the characters in [excludes]
  // now [characters] is an array too
  characters = characters.filter(c => !~excludes.indexOf(c));
  
  console.log(`excluded ${excludes.join("")}`)
  console.log(`[characters] now ${characters.join("")}`);
  
  // create an array with length [len], map characters (pseudo random) into it 
  // and return the joined array
  return [...Array(len)]
    .map(v => characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)])
    //                   ^ characters is array, so you can pick an element from it
    .join("");
}

// easier may be to initially use a subset
const createRandomIdSimple = (len, chars) => [...Array(len)]
    .map(v => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
    .join("");

const chars4Id = document.querySelector("#chars4RandomId").content.textContent.split("");;
console.log(`Your id from createRandomSimple: ${createRandomIdSimple(10, chars4Id)}`);
```

```html
<template id="excludes">DWX23Aal0gn</template>
<template id="chars4RandomId">BCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYZbcdefhijkmopqrstuvwxyz1456789</template>
```

**Bonus**: rewritten to a factory function for creating random Id's

```js
const randomId = RandomIdFactory();
const log = Logger();

log(`Lets create 25 pseudo random id's of length 32`,
  `without "l" (lowercase L) and "0" (zero):\n`,
  [...Array(25)].map(x => randomId(32, "l0")).join("\n"));

function RandomIdFactory() {
  const characters = [...Array(26)]
    .map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 65))
    .concat([...Array(26)].map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)))
    .concat([...Array(10)].map((x, i) => `${i}`));
    
  return (len, excludes) => {
    const chars = excludes && 
      characters.filter(c => !~excludes.indexOf(c)) ||
      characters;
    return [...Array(len)]
      .map(v => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
      .join("");
  };
}

function Logger() {
  const logEl = document.querySelector("#log") || (() => { 
    document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('pre'), {id:"log"}));
    return document.querySelector("#log");
  })();
  return (...strs) => strs.forEach(s => logEl.textContent += `${s}\n`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit this might be a little tortuous as solution...

```js
/*
 * Char codes ranges:
 *   0-9 -> 48-57
 *   A-Z -> 65-90
 *   a-z -> 97-122
 */

function makeId(idLength, charsToExclude = []) {
  // list of all invalid char codes between '0' (char code 48) and 'z' (char code 122)
  const invalidCharCodes = [58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96];

  // add to the invalid char list any char passed as parameter
  if (charsToExclude.length > 0) {
    charsToExclude.forEach(char => invalidCharCodes.push(char.charCodeAt(0)))
  }

  let id = '';

  while (id.length < idLength) {
    let charCode;

    do {
      charCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 48 + 1)) + 48;
    } while (invalidCharCodes.indexOf(charCode) >= 0)

    id += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }

  return id;
}


// test
console.log('should return an ID containing digits and letters (either lower or upper case):', makeId(10));
console.log('should return an ID containing only digits:', makeId(10, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']));
console.log('should return an ID containing only letters (either lower or upper case):', makeId(10, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']));
console.log('should return an ID containing only lower case letters:', makeId(10, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']));
console.log('should return an ID containing only upper case letters:', makeId(10, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']));
console.log('should return an ID containing only 0s:', makeId(10, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']));
```